# Can someone explain what this means **/*.js when trying to fetch the src files in my js directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

I'm trying to learn how to put a GulpJS file together and seeing the following source reference in some places **/*.js but unsure as to what exactly it means. Could someone explain what this is?

If my file structure is something like below, how would I access 
* each js file in each of the js libs and each js file in js src?
* how can i access each image?

```
css/
    libs/
        lib1.scss
        lib2.scss
    src/
        partials/
            partial1.scss
            partial2.scss
            partial3.scss
js/
    libs/
        lib1/
            lib11.js
        lib2/
            lib21.js
        lib3/
            lib31.js
    src/
        src1.js
        src2.js
        src3.js

img/
    imgs1/
        img11.jpg
        img12.jpg
        img13.png
    imgs2/
        img21.gif
        img22.png
        img23.jpg
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's helpful to have a basic understanding of pattern matching and the module that gulp is using to resolve those glob matches, ie https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch

### Globstar **

The `**` symbol you're asking about is known as the "globstar". In most unix pattern matching, the `*` can only represent one directory level:

```
"a/*/*.js"

a/b/app.js => MATCH
a/b/c/app.js => NO MATCH
a/app.js => NO MATCH
```

The globstar allows you to specifiy an unknown number of in-between directories, like so:

```
"a/**/*.js"

a/b/app.js => MATCH
a/b/c/app.js => MATCH
a/app.js => MATCH
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/app.js => MATCH
other/app.js => NO MATCH
```

### Negation

You can negate them with a prepended `!`:

```
["a/**/*.js", "!a/vendor/**/*.js"]

a/b/c/app.js => MATCH
a/vendor/b/backbone.js => NO MATCH
```

Useful for excluding vendor files from linting, etc.

### Multiple globs combined

You can also combine multiple globs in one array to include multiple patterns as one search.

```
["js/**/*.js", "img/**/*.png"]

js/a/b/app.js => MATCH
img/cat.png => MATCH
```

---

The glob you requested would be something like this:

```
["js/**/*.js", "img/**/*"]
```

Answer (score 5):

"**/*.js" means "all .js files in all directories under the current one, recursively".

Traditional "*/*.js" means "all .js files in all directories under the current one".

Answer (score 0):

`*` is almost universally a wildcard - which would match anything in that place.

**Example:**

So if you wanted to target both `libs` directories in `css` and `js` directories you could write `/*/libs/`

Comment: hey, so i tried './js/*/libs/' but this didnt seem to compile anything inside js libes?

Comment: You should try what @MarcoS wrote.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... `../` is the command of "going up one parent directory".  So, if it's `../../` - it's going up 2 directories.

Hence `../*` is same way of saying, 'any file that is one parent directory up'.  So, with that question of yours, `**/*.js` - it is same way of saying 'get any .js file from any parent directory that is one level above'.

When using wildcard `*` - it is recursive command.

Comment: hey, what if each js lib directory had multiple js files in it like say file.min.js file.js file.concat.js but i just wanted to add file.min.js to my compiled file?

Comment: If you mean that you want the specific file but any directory above?  then it'll be like this `**/file.min.js` and it'll search recursively.  Or even this `**/js/file.min.js` as of telling to search recursively for 'js' file that is one directory above, and if it finds, then it'll grab file.min.js.  (p.s. this is very powerful command that is being underestimated.  I use that approach LOTS for my server-side scripting).